# How to stop Ubuntu's Recovery Mode from timing out

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

Trying to work in Ubuntu's Recovery mode, I click on `Drop to root shell prompt`.  Then within about two minutes (before I can perform the task) I get a timeout message:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-di...\x2d900d\x2d4144dbce7bcd.device.
```

This doesn't happen with all my computers.

Can someone tell me what is causing this and how to disable the timeout or the timer?

I can alternatively use the Livemedia for the maintenance, but would like to fix the default **Ubuntu's Recovery Mode** if possible.

**The commands requested for review:**

This command is run from a Pendrive:

```
apollo@testnode1:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda6: 237713/5177344 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 2756254/20696576 blocks
```

These commands are run from the normal install:

```
apollo@testnode2:~$ swapon
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda5 partition 7.8G   0B   -1
apollo@testnode2:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.3G        1.3G        4.4G        278M        1.5G        5.3G
Swap:          7.8G          0B        7.8G
apollo@testnode2:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for apollo: 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="4E98CBF598CBD99B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="173f2864-89f9-43ca-b0e1-5eaafdab48d3"
/dev/sda2: UUID="90CE-9CE3" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="599b66e0-89e6-4b4e-9847-541faf11fdb9"
/dev/sda4: UUID="3874F30874F2C820" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="bf40e76a-f4bf-4f35-8e6e-8116dab7fc73"
/dev/sda5: UUID="c9334080-5716-4af6-8223-c2f7ab8b42be" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="SWAP" PARTUUID="c6c857f5-60d4-429a-88b3-e8f2295514c2"
/dev/sda6: UUID="183a59f8-4023-4204-bf16-ef9ab0c61c7e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4a51f6b5-089b-45ea-968f-21b41f9eb1c2"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="46b31443-958e-4bbd-a037-fbb9d8e0d7ce" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="65e17cc7-01"
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="swap" UUID="1be3310d-83f3-41b9-b9fe-a146965a0c38" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="65e17cc7-05"
/dev/sdb6: LABEL="data" UUID="8c4924cc-5aaf-44bb-8e60-f49ba1431148" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="65e17cc7-06"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="2f583e8e-2993-46d3-be1b-7abd83eec923"
apollo@testnode2:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=183a59f8-4023-4204-bf16-ef9ab0c61c7e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=90CE-9CE3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c9334080-5716-4af6-8223-c2f7ab8b42be none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The timeout message doesn't show anymore.  The Recovery Session, just continues into a reboot in about two minutes.

Comment: Please give us the full time out error message, if possible.

Comment: @heynnema I had typed the error message in because it came on a black screen and couldn't be copied and pasted.  I'll add and image to my question in a little bit.  The problem happens on a test machine of which isn't setup.  I was using the bench for a clients project which had to be delivered.  I didn't complete all the test from your answer, and was going to complete them and add those to my question first.  I thought by the time I complete the test it may resolve the issue.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry for taking so long in running the test and updating the question with the information, but it's added to the question.  I'm upvoting your answer because of the value in providing the issue has to do with the integrity of the system.  I'm leaving the resolved checkmark in hopes for an actual removal of the timeout.

Comment: Everything looks OK there. Try unplugging ALL USB devices, esp keyboards or other input devices, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: There's only two devices plugged into the computer.  The Keyboard/Mouse dongle and the secondary drive.  The penddrive was only plugged in so that I could perform the steps for you (the command for running `fsck`.  Of course you know if I unplug the keyboard/mouse dongle I won't be able to access the select the **Advance Options** menu.  I'm booting without the the pendrive and will confirm that it still times out.

Comment: I assume that you've got a Logitech keyboard/mouse and one Logitech USB dongle. Within 2 minutes of selecting recovery mode, either turn off the keyboard AND mouse, or unplug the dongle, and see if it still times out.

Comment: I rebooted with only the one dongle (the mouse/keyboard adapter).  As soon as I selected **Drop to root shell prompt** I removed the dongle.  Now only the monitor cable and power cable is plugged into the computer.  The time out still functions the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53423/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-heynnema).

Comment: Is this a laptop or a desktop machine? In `terminal` start `xev` and lets see if we can see some input coming in... hum... how could we eliminate a trackpad (assuming that you've got a laptop)? Thinking... does the timeout still occur if you're booted to Live DVD/USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step #1

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

## Step #2

To find the cause of your timeout... waiting for device... let's look at...

- boot normally, if you can *(or do the following from the # root prompt from above)*
- in `terminal` *(or # prompt)*, type:

  - `swapon`
  - `free -h`
  - `sudo blkid`
  - `cat /etc/fstab`
  - copy the above output to the clipboard and paste it into your question for review.

## Step #3

In reviewing the fstab, we found a problem with the efi partition.

We changed:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=90CE-9CE3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

to this:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=90CE-9CE3  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll perform the steps provided and advise give you the results.  I'll have to boot to a liveusb to perform the `fsck`.  Don't want to risk the timeout corrupting the process.

Comment: @George  While there may be other ways, you can output the commands provided by heynnema to a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) file and link the output to a comment.